# My code throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

My code throw NullPointerException in if (encryptedPinBlockKeySerialNumber.length() == 0 && encryptedPinBlock.length() != 0) {
            encryptedPinBlockKeySerialNumber = cksn;
        }

```
public void getDebitParameters (String realAmount, String amountPurchase, String pan, String cardName, String expiryDate, String ctrack1,
                                    String ctrack2, String ctrack3, String cksn, String devID, String emvICCData, Enums.WSAction intAction,
                                    Enums.WSMobileAppTransType transactionType, Enums.WSAccountType accTypeId, String encryptedPinBlock, String encryptedPinBlockKeySerialNumber, boolean fallback ) {


        if (encryptedPinBlockKeySerialNumber.length() == 0 && encryptedPinBlock.length() != 0) {
            encryptedPinBlockKeySerialNumber = cksn;
        }

        try {
            // with (EPB)EncryptedPinBlock
            /* card_action = 1-Swipe, 2-Insert realamount = Double.parseDouble(realAmount);*/
            realamount = realAmount;
            displayamount = amountPurchase;
            cardnum = pan;
            track1 = ctrack1;
            track2 = ctrack2;
            track3 = ctrack3;
            cardHolderName = cardName;
            date = expiryDate;
            ksn = cksn;
            strDevID = devID;
            emvData = emvICCData;
            card_action = intAction;
            mobile_app_trans_type = transactionType;
            account_type = accTypeId;
            epb = encryptedPinBlock;
            epbKsn = encryptedPinBlockKeySerialNumber;
            isfallback = fallback;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            errorOccured();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that the encryptedPinBlockKeySerialNumber and encryptedPinBlock is initialized before using them in above code.